# Appropriate expressions of jealousy

Tags: méxico

A friend of mine in Mexico invited my roommate, LaPorte, and I to an event. I am unable to attend, but my roommate is. In my response, expressing how I wish I could come, I want to say something similar to this English phrase:

> I'm jealous that LaPorte gets to eat some of your amazing food!

My first thought was to write:

> Estoy celoso que LaPorte va a disfrutar la comida rica que siempre cocinan

But then I felt like celoso might be too strong of a word in this context so I thought maybe I should write:

> Me esta dando envidia que LaPorte va a disfrutar la comida rica que siempre cocinan

Help me better understand how to appropriately express jealousy in Spanish in this context and maybe in others as well.

Comment: Nice question, but it would be better if you rephrase this to ask the appropriate use of "celos" and "envidia" and which one of those to use for this case. This is a psychology page that talks about the differences http://www.inteligencia-emocional.org/cursos-gratis/celos/celos_y_envidia.htm but is in Spanish.

Comment: Envidia es mucho más apropiado en este caso. Celos es más apropiado cuando te "ningunean" amorosa, personal o profesionalmente.

Comment: Note that "jealousy" isn't even the right word in English, which will make translation difficult. You're really talking about envy--which are often confused (at least in English), but are quite separate.

Comment: Awesome comments, references, and answers, I was feeling like celos didn't sound quite right. I wish I could upvote these comments and answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With that context, the most appropriate one would be a variation of the third one:

> Me da envidia que LaPorte va a comer (o va a disfrutar) su excelente comida, y yo no.

At the end, emphasizing that you won't be able to enjoy it.